# What is the correct distribution?

Tags: distributions, frequency

Let, I have the following Frequency Distribution:

[image]

Which one would be the correct Grouped frequency Table if class-width = $1.0$?

$Table\#1$

[image]

$Table\#2$

[image]

Explain "**Why**".

What would be the answer if $\#$ of groups = $5$?

Comment: Table#1 is the correct one, because # of groups = 6 in Table#2.

Comment: I think there are two questions: (a) The first interval of table #1 is effectively longer than the others. For five intervals of equal length you need intervals something like (0.00-0.92), (0.93-2.94), ..., (3.99-5.00), in which intervals are effectively a little longer than 1.00. (b) #2 has six intervals of effective length 1.00.

Answer (score 1):

We use R statistical software to show five intervals of equal width
for the data in your Question.

You have data:

```
x = c(0, 2, 2.8,2.8,2.8, 3,3,3, 3.5, 4,4,4, 4.5, 5,5)
table(x)
x
0   2 2.8   3 3.5   4 4.5   5 
1   1   3   3   1   3   1   2
```

You need six equally spaced boundary points for five intervals. One possible
choice of boundaries is shown below.

```
bdy = seq(-.09, 5.01, by=1.02);  bdy
[1] -0.09  0.93  1.95  2.97  3.99  5.01
diff(bdy)  # verify equal lengths 1.02
[1] 1.02 1.02 1.02 1.02 1.02
```

Make a frequency histogram of the data using these intervals. (Notice that
one of the intervals turns out to be empty.)

```
hist(x, br=bdy, col="skyblue2", label=T, ylim=c(0,7))
rug(x, col="red")
```

The statement `rug` puts red tick marks along the horizontal axis, showing
locations of observations. (Tied values are represented by only one tick mark.)

[image]

Here is a 'stripchart', which shows each individual observation. (The data values are exactly at the centers of the boxes.) Vertical lines show
the boundaries.

```
stripchart(x, method="stack")
abline(v=bdy, col="green3")
```

[image]